# Google Chrome doesn´t resize img

Tags: html, image, google-chrome

When I have parental element with width 30% and child element with 100% all browsers resize height of img to preserve proportions. But in chrome is just extends and deform. Does anyone heard about this?

I don´t know how to make code of that problem so I will just put here a link.
http://almaweby.cz/reference.html

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting `height: auto`?

Comment: do you really need to use `flex-box`? try to change display for `div class="hook"` elements for `display:inline-block` and then the images should behave correctly, OR put your `<img>` elements into extra containers, eg. `<div><img/></div>`, then the flex-box should affect div's rather than `img` elements.

Comment: @Paweł thanks, I used the second solution because I used to have it in inline-block but then my js didn´t work properly. Post a answer to enable me mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change display for `div class="hook"` elements for `display:inline-block` and then the images should behave correctly, OR Put your `<img>` elements into extra containers, eg. `<div><img/></div>`, then the flex-box should affect div's rather than `img` elements.

Answer (score 0):

i think its resizing in chrome, 
My chrome showing small images..